# random.choice() with sample only being able to be selected a maximum of 2 times

Tags: python, random

I want to do a random.choice() but the same sample can only be selected a maximum of 2 times?

```py
import collections
import numpy as np
l_ev=[]
list_items=['aa', 'bb', 'cc','dd', 'ee']

num=3
for i in range(3):

    l_objects_draw = np.random.choice(list_items, num)
    print('draw: '+str(l_objects_draw))
    l_ev.extend(l_objects_draw)
    print('l_ev' + str(l_ev))
    dup = [item for item, count in collections.Counter(l_ev).items() if count > 1]
    print('dup: ' + str(dup))
    list= [x for x in list_items if x not in dup]
    print('new list' + str(list_items))
```

should randomly select from list but cannot return any item from the list more than more than 2 times for example.

Currently, if 'aa' is selected in the first iteration of the for loop, it is not removed from the list since it is only selected once. it could be that in the second iteration of the loop, 'aa' is selected twice eg and then only removed from the list.

This would mean that l_ev may contain 3 'aa' elements. I want to avoid this. but preserve the number of items selected in each iteration ie 'num' hence I simply can not remove it.

Comment: `choice` returns a single element anyway. Did you mean `random.sample`?

Comment: Maybe you could approach this another way? I'm thinking `L = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc'] * 2; random.shuffle(L)`

Comment: Beside the point, but `list` is a bad variable name since it [shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the [builtin `list` type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list). In a tiny example like this it's not a big problem, but in more involved code, it's better to use a more descriptive name, or at least something like `lst` or `L`. For an example of a situation you could get yourself into, see [TypeError: 'list' object is not callable](/q/31087111/4518341).

Comment: @DeepSpace in both choice and sample one can set the sample size

Comment: You are confusing `choice` with `choices`. [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) accepts a single argument

Comment: the docstring signature for `np.random.choice` suggests multiple arguments and indeed thats the behavior I observe: `choice(a, size=None, replace=True, p=None)`

Comment: `random.choice` != `np.random.choice`

Comment: ok but i cant use random choice because i need to specify the number of samples to select ie 'num'